# Módulo não localizado - "module xxx not found" - Lua lang

Tags: lua, require

Arquivo: Player.lua, meu módulo

```lua
  local Player = {}
  local function funcPlayer()

    local player = {}
    local self = {name="", points = 0}

    local setPoints = function(newPoints)
      self.points = newPoints
    end

    local getPoints = function ()
      return self.points
    end

    local setName = function(newName)
      self.name = newName
    end

    local getName = function()
      return self.name
    end

    local f__tostring = function()
      return "(" .. self.name .. ", " .. self.points .. ")"
    end

    setmetatable(player, {
      __tostring = f__tostring
    })

    player.getPoints = getPoints
    player.setPoints = setPoints
    player.getName = getName
    player.setName = setName

    return player
end

Player = funcPlayer()
return Player
```

Arquivo que solicita o modulo: Players.lua

```lua
  local tabPlyer = require("Player")
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
[Running] lua "c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua"
lua: c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua:1: module 'Player' not found:
    no field package.preload['Player']
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\lua\Player\init.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player\init.lua'
    no file '.\Player.lua'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player.dll'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\Player.dll'
    no file 'c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\Player52.dll'
    no file '.\Player52.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    c:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games\Players.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

O que fazer para conseguir usar este módulo?

Estou usando VSCode.

Variável PATH: ...; C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua

Variável LUA_PATH: C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua

Caminho de Lua: C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua

Caminho do script: C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games

Comment: Onde está o módulo Player.lua? Veja na mensagem de erro aonde Lua procurou o módulo.

Comment: Em:"C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua\ScriptLua\Games". Já alterei o arquivo de lugar, para por exemplo "C:\Users\tct9\Documents\Lua", mas o erro continua o mesmo.